# roblox struggling with cframe

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm recently making a game like "The Strongest Battlegrounds" on `roblox` but I encountered a problem.
I can't explain the problem due to my bad English but here is the video of the problem.

[link](https://streamable.com/wlavax)

as you can see in the video it sometimes work as intended but sometimes its just being broken
(by the way you can see the console on the video)

Never mind here is my code:

```
local hitbox = script.Parent
local player = hitbox.Stats.Player
local tweenservice = game:GetService("TweenService")

hitbox.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local humanoid = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        if player.Value ~= hit.Parent.Name then
            hitbox.CanTouch = false
            local plr = game.Players:WaitForChild(player.Value)
            game.ReplicatedStorage.Ability1:FireClient(plr)
            local char = plr.Character
            local torso = char.Torso
            local rootpart = char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
            local rightarm = char:WaitForChild("Right Arm")
            local char2 = hit.Parent
            local rootpart2 = char2.HumanoidRootPart
            local head = char2:WaitForChild("Head")
            char.Torso.CanCollide = false
            char2.Torso.CanCollide = false
            char.Head.CanCollide = false
            char2.Head.CanCollide = false
            rootpart.Anchored = true
            --local oldcframe = rootpart.CFrame
            --char.Humanoid.AutoRotate = false
            rootpart.CanCollide = false
            rootpart2.CanCollide = false
            char.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 0
            
            
            local count = 0
    --      local oldpos = rootpart.Position
            while wait(0.01) do
                char.Torso.CanCollide = false
                char2.Torso.CanCollide = false
                char.Head.CanCollide = false
                char2.Head.CanCollide = false
                --rootpart.CFrame = oldcframe

                rootpart2.CFrame = torso.CFrame + (torso.CFrame.LookVector*2)
                if rootpart2.CFrame ~= (torso.CFrame.LookVector*2) then
                    print("rootpart2 cframe is not same with torso cframe")
                    rootpart2.CFrame = torso.CFrame + (torso.CFrame.LookVector*2)
                    if rootpart2.CFrame == (torso.CFrame.LookVector*2) then
                        print("but now its same")
                    else
                        print("tried to equalize the values but failed")
                    end
                end
                print("torso: cframe", (torso.CFrame.LookVector*2))
                print("rootpart2 cframe:", rootpart2.CFrame)
                --  rootpart2.CFrame = rootpart2.CFrame + (-rootpart2.CFrame.LookVector*0.1)
                --  rootpart2.CFrame = rootpart2.CFrame + (-rootpart2.CFrame.UpVector*1)
                count += 1
                if count == 30 then
                    rootpart.Anchored = false
                    break
                end 
            end
            
            
            --char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart").CFrame = char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart").CFrame + (-char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart").CFrame.UpVector*0.5)
            count = 0
            while wait(0.01) do
                char.Torso.CanCollide = false
                char2.Torso.CanCollide = false
                char.Head.CanCollide = false
                char2.Head.CanCollide = false
                --rootpart.CFrame = oldcframe

                rootpart2.CFrame = torso.CFrame + (torso.CFrame.LookVector*2)
                if rootpart2.CFrame ~= (torso.CFrame.LookVector*2) then
                    print("rootpart2 cframe is not same with torso cframe")
                    rootpart2.CFrame = torso.CFrame + (torso.CFrame.LookVector*2)
                    if rootpart2.CFrame == (torso.CFrame.LookVector*2) then
                        print("but now its same")
                    else
                        print("tried to equalize the values but failed")
                    end
                end
                print("torso: cframe", (torso.CFrame.LookVector*2))
                print("rootpart2 cframe:", rootpart2.CFrame)
                --  rootpart2.CFrame = rootpart2.CFrame + (-rootpart2.CFrame.LookVector*0.1)
                --  rootpart2.CFrame = rootpart2.CFrame + (-rootpart2.CFrame.UpVector*1)
                count += 1
                rootpart.Anchored = false
                if count == 10 then
                    break
                end 
            end
            local goal = {}
            goal.CFrame = rootpart.CFrame + (rootpart.CFrame.LookVector*35)
            local tweeninfo = TweenInfo.new(0.5)
            local throw = tweenservice:Create(rootpart2, tweeninfo, goal)
            throw:Play()
            char.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 0
            rootpart2.Anchored = false
            char2.Head.CanCollide = true
            char.Head.CanCollide = true
            wait(0.1)
            wait()
            char.Torso.CanCollide = true
            char.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
            --char.Humanoid.AutoRotate = true
            rootpart.CanCollide = true
            rootpart2.CanCollide = true
            char2.Torso.CanCollide = true
            script.Parent:Destroy()
            
        end
    end
end)
```

If its hard-coded and confusing sorry for that.
By the way, if you can do the same thing with another method let me know thanks.

I literally tried everything, I looked for the internet all the forum sites but I didn't find anything.

As you can see i played with the code a little bit but no, I'm struggling for this problem for hours now.

Note: Its not a problem with look vector I removed it but the same problem continued.